# Controller that calls a partial view that should display inside the Layout view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In a standard MVC application we have **_Layout.cshtml** and an **Index.cshtml** view. Now imagine if the user receives an email activation after a registration and now he/she clicks on that link.

The link points to /Account/ActivateAccount and after I process the activation, I wanted to redirect the user to the Login.cshtml partial view displaying a message.

I'm aware I can pass the message via the TempData["Message"] but what I don't know is how to redirect to a partial view and have that display inside the **_Layout.cshtml** instead that by itself.

At least this is what is happening when I call **RedirectToAction("Login", "Home")**

Note: all "home" based partial views are displaying within a < div id="divmain"> and my ideal solution would be to be able to decide what view should display inside that div, **from the controller**.

What's the right way to call a Partial View to be displayed **from within another Controller** ??

Comment: so now when you redirect the user to login view only the partial view is displayed without layout ?

Comment: as I guess home/login action return PartialView(). do you really need that ? I mean have you considered returning a View() ? cause when returning a partial view layout will not be rendered. that is the point of partial view. So in you case if you return View() there won't be any problem I guess

Comment: and the RedirectToAction would work as excepted than

Comment: I have 4 or 5 partial views that i display inside the Home Page (aka _Layout) and each one replaces the content of a divMain. Not sure I was planning to change all that !!

Comment: they are inside razor right ? like this @Partial()

Comment: No, they are all <a class="nav-link" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Get" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#divmain" href="/Home/Pricing">PRICING</a>   ..at least so far :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48784/discussion-between-dima-and-eager-to-learn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question but I think what you're asking is if you can call a partial view from the _layout? This can be done with `@Html.Action()` helper. It will call out to a controller and method you specify and insert the result. The method you call would just be a PartialResult that returns the partial view with whatever data you need.

This is in contrast to `@Html.Partial()` which will render the partial view in place with whatever data you provide without routing back through a controller.

EDIT:

To summarize the comments to this answer, it seems I misunderstood the requirement. A user receives an email and clicks the link to activate their registration. The controller action that handles that request activates the user and then it needs to redirect to something. In this case, there was already a partial view which would serve the purpose but it couldn't be redirected to directly for some reasons. My suggestion was to just create a new View which contained a `@Html.Partial()` call to basically wrap the partial in a full view page.

The action method which handled the click could then just return that view directly or, if you consider the click of the link to be a "post" since it changes the application model by validating the user, you would create a new controller action and `return RedirectToAction()` directly. This would be like following the Post, Redirect, Get method and would prevent some issue if the user tried to refresh the "activated" page. It would also give more control over the URL naming.

Comment: What I meant was how to call a partial view from a "controller" as soon as my ActivateAccount controller process the activation, I wanted to redirect the user to the PartialView Login...

Comment: That's what I'm having trouble with. You don't "call" a view. Views are rendered. You can provide them with data which they will render but you don't call them.

Comment: Sorry - you edited after I replied. So you have a link from an email a user clicks. That will send them to a controller method. Does the user need to see anything in order to "complete" the activation? Or can the controller do it all itself and just redirect the user at the end? If the latter, the controller will just `return RedirectToAction()` specifying the new controller action you want to take over. Or you can `return View("SomeOtherViewName")` if you don't need a controller action to do more work.

Comment: The activation controller does everything automatically, but the RedirectToAction is what is not working, cause if I put the Login PartialView, that view displays on the browser without the main page _Layout. That's exactly the problem I have right now...

Comment: You can't redirect to a partial view. Well, you can, but you're returning a partial result. If you don't have a full View that already suits the purpose, just make a new View who immediately just has a @Html.Partial() to render the desired partial. The _layout will be rendered, you won't duplicate the code of the partial and you have a fully formed page. Unless I'm still misunderstanding.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are saying to create an empty View named "Activated" that has a @Html.Action inside the Razor HTML that loads the Login Partial View and the url on the browser will look like http://xxx/Activated  ..is that right?

Comment: If that's what you need, sure. I was just suggesting creating a view with a simple @Html.Partial to render your partial view. In the controller that activates the registration, you would either return View("Activated", optional_model) or return RedirectToAction() in which case you would then need a new controller action to handle any further work before returning the view. If you return the View directly, the URL will be whatever was clicked by the user. If you create a new controller method, you can decide what the URL is by virtual of the action and controller names.

Comment: Updated my answer to sort of summarize this chain and be a little more explicit, possibly.